# Apk de OCR , ndk build não quer instalar

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Há uns dias desenvolvi uma apk de reconhecimento de texto OCR, para fazer esta aplicação foi necessário instalar o ndk-build. Preciso de dar continuação da aplicação mas num novo computador, no entanto, o ndk-build não quer instalar, fecha automaticamente. O que acho estranho porque o computador atual é melhor.

Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma apk OCR sem ter que instalar o ndk-build?

Comment: Está a programar com que editor/compilador? 
Caso seja o Eclipse verifique que tem a versão mais recente!

Comment: Esta nas tags da pergunta estou a usar o android-studio